# gulp.src base using wrong directory

Tags: gulp, radix

I'm having a little trouble with the base file. To make things short - here's my code...

```
gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  return gulp.src(['www/pages/**/*.html'], {base: 'pages'})
    .pipe(fileInclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www/tmp/html/pages/'));
});
```

When I run fileinclude I want to take all the folders shown below and then send them to `tmp/pages/page-*/index.html` Keeping the file structure. However, for some reason It adds a `www` to the beginning of the file structure.

```
www
|-- pages
|   |-- page-1
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |-- page-2
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |-- page-3
|   |   |-- index.html
```

Can't seem to get my head around it and I've tried a few things but I keep getting an extra `www` so it turns out to be `www/tmp/html/www/pages/**/*.html`

Comment: change base to `{base: 'www/pages'}` should solve your original issue

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go against using base and was going to try something different.

In my attempts. I somehow managed to get it working by simple using the src as `www/pages/**/*.html` and dest as `www/tmp/html/pages/`

This meant that all folders with .html after pages was picked up and then created in `www/tmp/html/pages/**/index.html`

I think I saw it as lot more difficult that it actually was...